# Extract file name from a sub string

Tags: python

I have to find the file name in the following scenario

I hv structure like .. folder_folder_filename ..
sometime i have _ in file name in the last.like ..ABC_.pdf
how can I extract the file name in that case

example of file name
Abc_12_test_.pdf ---> output ---test.pdf

bc_122_testfile_.pdf->output-->testfile.pdf

test_.xlsx---Output --> test.xlsx

it is not always the case that folder be part of the string.

so if _.exists in last of file name.. I have to find file name between two _.

here is sameple code .. it is not working for all the cases.

```
        file_name= file_name.split('_')[-1]
        if file_name[0]=='.':
            if "_" not in file_name:
                pattern = "(.*?)_."
                print('pattern 1')
            else:
                pattern = "_(.*?)_."
                print('pattern 2')
            file_name = os.path.join(root, name)
            file_name = re.search(pattern, file_name).group(1)enter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, make it look for non `_` characters:

```
def filename(s):
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(s))
    name = re.findall("[^_]+", name)[-1]
    return name + ext

tests = [
    "Abc_12_test_.pdf",
    "bc_122_testfile_.pdf",
    "test_.xlsx"
]
for t in tests:
    print(f"{t} --> {filename(t)}")
```

Output:

```
Abc_12_test_.pdf --> test.pdf
bc_122_testfile_.pdf --> testfile.pdf
test_.xlsx --> test.xlsx
```

Comment: Thanks it is working .. Actually I have my file path are like this ..C:\Dt\foler\A\test_.docx. and I am passing this as whole string. it is not working only in this case. rest is fine. it is returning  C:\Dt\foler\A est.docx

Comment: I've updated to use only the basename.

Comment: it is working fine in all the case except in case when file is like this..C:\Dt\AC\D\2nd_Docv_01.02_04.01.02.02.03.141.04 SS TTOut DSA_.dgn.htm. it is returning .dbn.htm

Comment: this looks to be failing in the double extensions in file name